# 500 error while accessing one of the action

Tags: java, struts

I am facing following error while accessing one of the action

> HTTP Status 500 - No action instance for path /ACTIONURL could be created

Entry in struts-cofig.xml:

```
<action
path="/ACTIONURL"
type="com.pkc.ActionClass"
name="formname"
input="SomeJSP.jsp"
validate="true">

    <forward name =".."></forward>
</action>
```

Comment: can you post whole stacktrace

Comment: where would `..` lead for a path under the root?

Comment: please can you post formbean tag of ur struts config

Comment: @rsp ".." is nothing i am just using a dummy alias for my Tile.

Comment: @Damdor <form-bean
name="formname"
type="com.pkg.form.formclassName">
</form-bean>

Comment: In addition, Form validations are working fine. And corrosponding logs are being printed properly.

Answer (score 0):

If your Struts Servlet contains a `url-pattern` of this effect:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ActionServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Then, you access your action like this:

```
http://<server>:<port>/<myApp>/ACTIONURL.do
```

(See how I added the `.do` to the action path).

Comment: so, do you add a `.do` to your url?

Comment: what exception/stacktrace does your webapp throw?

Comment: There is no exception in catalina log. Only on browser i am facing error which is mentioned in QT